# Why is my put request not returning anything findByIdAndUpdate

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I am testing my put request which is returning nothing, it also isn't working when im trying to use it via the client. When i test it in insomnia i get a 200 message but the body returns null instead of the updated user.

Below is the code for the request via the client which also gives the ability to update the users profile photo:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const updatedUser = {
      userId: user._id,
      username,
      email,
      password,
    }
    if (file){
      const data = new FormData()
      const filename = Date.now()+file.name;
      data.append("name",filename)
      data.append("file",file)
      updatedUser.profilePic = filename;
      try {
        await axios.put("http://localhost:5000/api/users/"+user._id, updatedUser)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
  }
```

Below is the code for the request via my API

```
router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.userId === req.params.id) {
      if (req.body.password) {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        req.body.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
      }
      try {
        const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
          req.params.id,
          {
            $set: req.body,
          },
          { new: true }
        );
        res.status(200).json(updatedUser);
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
        console.log(err)
      }
    } else {
      res.status(401).json("You can update only your account!");
    }
  });
```

here is my user schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    profilePic:{
        type: String,
        default:"",
    }
},
{timestamps:true}
)

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema)
```

Comment: Do you send and existing User id in the req.params?

Comment: yes i do, i also test it in insomnia with the user id at the end of the url and add the new username etc. to the body and it comes up with 200 response but no data to show the updated user

Comment: Can you add User schema and the request body in insomnia?

Comment: What is the output `console.log("body: ", req.body)`?

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```js
const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  req.params.id,
  {
    $set: req.body,
  },
  { new: true, useFindAndModify: false }
);
```

Comment: i tried this but still having the same issue

Comment: can you console log `req.params.id` and `req.body.userId` @bootygrocery1000

Comment: so i console log the body in the try statement when i get the 200 and i get returned the user id and the updated username : body:  { userId: '647fb8603a389d05ed54f***', username: 'ryan10000' },  but in the response its still null, it also doesn't update in mongodb database and the username is still the old one 'ryan1000'

Comment: I don't understand  this condition: `if (req.body.userId === req.params.id)`
I think it's not necessary.

Comment: its to. check that the user id of the user trying to update the settings matches the user thats logged in

Comment: So, You needn't check it if each user can only change his profile. Please remove it, or check whether the condition is true or not by logging it.